# Unable To Upload File Using Webrequest Method In C#

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am trying To upload proof of address using rest api service of voxbone.
  But I am Getting An Error : "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
When i have contacted tech support team team of voxbone they are saying that my request is not reaching there system....
please can i have some help to sort out this problem

```
 WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create("https://sandbox.voxbone.com/ws-voxbone/services/rest/regulation/address 
    "); 
    myReq.Method = method; 
    myReq.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary= XXX"; 
    string username = xxxxxx; 
    string password = xxxxxx;

    string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;

    UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();


    myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(enc.GetBytes(usernamePassword)));

    string str2 = " 
    --XXX 
    Content-ID: createRegulationAddressRequest 
    Content-Type: application/json

    { 
    "salutation" : "MR", 
    "companyName" : null, 
    "companyDescription" : null, 
    "firstName" : "rahul", 
    "lastName" : "singh", 
    "buildingNumber" : "23",     
    "identityDocumentProof" : 
    { 
    "Nationality" : "IND", 
    "identityDocumentType" : "NATIONAL_ID_CARD", 
    "identityDocumentNumber" : "jfklajfljsdfl;dslfj" , 
    "issuingAuthority" : "jkhkjhkj", 
    "issuingDate" : "2017-11-30" 
    } , 
    "extraFields" : 
    { 
    "Signatory date of birth" : "1993-01-05", 
    "Signatory place of birth" : "varanasi,India", 
    "Signatory tax code" : "dsdfsfsdf" 
    } 
    } 
    --XXX-- 
    Content-ID: proofOfIdentityDocument 
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 
    Content-Disposition: file-data; name="proofOfIdentityDocument"; filename=stripe.png

    Wuppertal

    --XXX--"; 

    byte[] buffer3 = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(str2);

    string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer3 ); 
    Stream reqstr = myReq.GetRequestStream(); 
    reqstr.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
    reqstr.Close();

    WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse(); 
    Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream(); 
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8); 
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: TBH if you actually got a response, and it was 500, that suggests the request _is_ reaching their service, but their site is crashing. Possibly it even crashes before the request gets logged, or there is some intermediate service on their network which isn't processing and forwarding the request correctly. It's hard to know. But you can probably prove it's at least hitting their URL by monitoring your network requests with Wireshark, or Fiddler or something.

Comment: If they are saying that it didn't reach them, I would suspect that there is a missing or wrong parameter in your call.

Comment: is my code is correct

Comment: who knows, we have no idea whether that's the right data to submit, we don't know whatever API it is you're calling. Check their docs for an example of a valid request. The way you build the request is a bit convoluted, but it looks ok at a glance. Like I said, you can debug it and check the content of the HTTP request, check exactly where it goes to and what exact response you get, by using the network using the tools I mentioned.

Comment: @AmrElgarhy if the server actually responded as described in the question, this should indicate that the server received the request. The 500 suggests it may not have been able to process it, and may not have got round to logging it before it crashed, but it suggests it received it. If there was an incorrect parameter in the request, then really the server should have returned a 400 (Bad Request) to indicate that. So unless it's badly configured, it seems more likely to be a fault on the remote server. As I said, OP can use the relevant tools to prove he's hitting the remote server.

Comment: @ADyson I know what you mean, 500 server side call means they have received the call for sure, but note that If you sent a null parameter to an API method which is waiting integer for example  this will return a 500 error code not 404.

Comment: so when we get bad request error @AmrElgarhy ??

Comment: @RahulSingh when you call a non existing API method

Comment: I notice you are trying to set the username and password to xxxxxx without  enclosing them in quotes.

Comment: null parameter or invalid model in general should return badrequest HTTP code 400,

Comment: @Coder1409 I agree but Web API has an annoying habit of crashing when expecting a non-nullable int which isn't included in the request or is included but set to null. It ought to return 400 but I think the deserialiser falls over before that point so you get a hard-to-trace 500 instead.

Comment: @AmrElgarhy calling a non-existing method would get you a 404 (Not Found), not a 400 (Bad Request). Calling an existing method but with the wrong parameters would get you a 400. Completely mangling the request would potentially result in a 500 if the server just has no idea what to do.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, you are right, I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

From Voxbone [Error codes docs](https://developers.voxbone.com/docs/v3/errors/):

> FIELD_MISSING 500 Missing field.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Looking at the list I think these are not HTTP error codes, but bespoke ones. I suspect these would be contained within a successful (200 OK) response. A 500 (Internal Server Error) (note that this description was specifically reported by the OP, not "Missing field") is a server-level HTTP status code which suggests the server failed to process the request at all. Unless of course the OP has given us bad information. If they _are_ using HTTP response codes to represent these error statuses then it's a pretty gross abuse of the HTTP standard.

Comment: @ADyson Yes bespoke, what I understand that if they return 500 code, that means they received a call, how come they will return a status code for a not received request, they are just not logging the call if it didn't pass the parameters validations.

Comment: " how come they will return a status code for a not received request"...I don't understand your point. If the server returns "Internal Server Error" then the request _must_ have reached the webserver, because it's the webserver which has to give that response. If the request never reached the server it would time out, or be unable to resolve the host or something. You'd never get any kind of response. If OP's info is correct then for the support to claim the request was never received is simply incorrect. Maybe the server didn't log it, but it certainly received it, and then crashed.

Comment: @ADyson yes that what I meant exactly, I didn’t describe it as well as you did, thanks.

Comment: Ok good. But my point in my original comment above is that this isn't the answer to the question, because the error code shown in the docs you've linked to does not appear to be the same thing as the error that the OP is reporting.

Comment: No. OP clearly states the error message returned along with the 500 status is "Internal Server Error". This generic, produced by all webservers when the script crashes. If the code above was being referred to, the message would not say this, because a) it would make no sense to say that. If anything it would say "Missing field" in the message. b) I do not believe that these codes are HTTP status codes, or that they are returned by setting the HTTP status, because they don't mean the same as what the standard HTTP codes do, and there are too many.

Comment: Furthermore, looking at the tutorials on the site (e.g. https://www.voxbone.com/blog/automating-your-did-provisioning-with-slack-voxapi-part-1/) in one example it shows the client code looking in the response body for error codes (e.g. `body.errors[0].apiErrorMessage`, which suggests strongly to me that a voxbone "error" would actually generate a "200 OK" HTTP status (or maybe a 400 in some cases, depending on their implementation) and then have these error codes contained within an "errors" section within some JSON in the response body.

Comment: A 500 Internal Server Error would only be if the server cannot make any other kind of rational response to the request, either because of a bug in the server code, or that the request is completely un-interpretable.

Comment: @ADyson I understand your point, it makes sense, but my thinking was if they are sending just 500 http status , the browser will show the message internal server error.

Comment: there's no browser involved here, but anyway the HTTP client will just show whatever is sent by the server. If there's a status code included but no status message, then it might report a default message, yes, but most servers don't do that. And it's highly unlikely this server would do that if it _was_ abusing HTTP status codes, because it would clearly be confusing to callers, and for the ones which are not standard HTTP codes the client would certainly need a message in order to display anything useful. It would be likely to display the messages shown in the docs.

Comment: Furthermore again, (and this is a bit speculative, but here you go) - reading the docs, blogs and tutorials on the site I get the impression the makers of this are fairly switched-on web 2.0 type of people and would be unlikely to so blatantly abuse HTTP standards in this way. However, it's a shame their docs are not a bit clearer and give a specific example of how to expect an error code to appear.

Comment: @ADyson yes, very miss leading.

Comment: @ADyson you might be 100% right, to be sure the OP should contact them with these questions